# Tkinter: Launching process creates not-wanted new window

Tags: python, windows, opencv, tkinter, customtkinter

I have built a gui for a script using customtkinter.

When I generate an executable file of the code with Py installer, once I run it, it generates a second app window every time I hit the button start process, which triggers a function to process the video frames.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
from yolo import plot_bboxes
from ultralytics import YOLO
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Label, filedialog
import os
import csv
import tempfile
import threading
import time
from customtkinter import CTkImage
from PIL import Image


customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


cap = None
video_speed = 1
video_state = 'playing'

if not os.path.exists('detection'):
    os.makedirs('detection')
    
# Create a global variable to store a reference to the CSV file
csvfile = None
# Open a CSV file in write mode
csvfile = open(f'./detection/inference.csv', 'w', newline='')
# Create a CSV writer object
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
# Write the header row
writer.writerow(['filename','frame_number', 'frame_time', 'class_name', 'confidence', 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'])

is_paused = False
current_frame=0
xvel=1
temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
frame_dir = os.path.join(temp_dir.name, 'frames')
os.makedirs(frame_dir)


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.iconbitmap(".\icon.ico")
        # configure window
        self.title("DAIS - Inference App")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")
        
        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Settings", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.select_model,text='Select Model')
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.select_video,text='Select Video')
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.start_processing,text='Start Processing')
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.progressbar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(self.sidebar_frame,mode='determinate',)
        self.progressbar.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(20, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.progressbar.set(0)
        
        #appearence settings
        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Mode:")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=10, pady=(0, 0),sticky='w')
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self, values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                       command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))
        #self.scaling_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="UI Scaling:", anchor="e")
        #self.scaling_label.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        #self.scaling_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self, values=["80%", "90%", "100%", "110%", "120%"],command=self.change_scaling_event)
        #self.scaling_optionemenu.grid(row=11, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 20))


        #create videolabel
        self.centerbar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.centerbar_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.centerbar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.video_label= customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.centerbar_frame,text='')      
        self.video_label.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="")
        self.timeline = customtkinter.CTkSlider(self,command=self.update_frame,from_=0, to=100)
        self.timeline.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=(40, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")
        self.timeline.set(0)
        

        # create checkbox and switch frame
        self.checkbox_slider_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.checkbox_slider_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew",rowspan=5)

        self.param_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.checkbox_slider_frame, text="Parameters", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.param_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))    

        self.confidence_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame, text='Confidence:')
        self.confidence_text.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(0, 0), sticky="sw")
        self.confidence = customtkinter.CTkSlider(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame,command=self.update_confidence,from_=0, to=100)
        self.confidence.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="new")
        self.confidence.set(25)
        self.confidence_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame,text='25%')
        self.confidence_value.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(10, 0), pady=(0, 0), sticky="n")
        
        self.skipscale_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame, text='FPS:')
        self.skipscale_text.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(0, 0), sticky="sw")
        self.skipscale = customtkinter.CTkSlider(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame,command=self.update_fps,from_=1, to=60)
        self.skipscale.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.skipscale.set(10)
        self.skipscale_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame,text=10)
        self.skipscale_value.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=(10, 0), pady=(0, 0), sticky="n")
        
        #DaisLOGO
        self.my_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("daislogo1.png"),dark_image=Image.open("daislogoblanco.png"), size=(200, 100))
        self.image_label =customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, image=self.my_image, text="")
        self.image_label.grid(row=9, column=2, rowspan=2, sticky="s")

        
        #play pause next prev buttons
        self.play_pause_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Pause", command=self.toggle_pause)
        self.play_pause_button.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=(20, 0), padx=20, sticky="n")
        
        #play pause next prev buttons
        self.next_frame_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Next", command=self.next_frame)
        self.next_frame_button.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=(20, 0), padx=20, sticky="ne")
        #play pause next prev buttons
        self.prev_frame_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Prev", command=self.prev_frame)
        self.prev_frame_button.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=(20, 0), padx=20, sticky="nw")
        
        
        #Display speed    
        self.speed_button = customtkinter.CTkSegmentedButton(self, values=["1x", "2x", "3x"],
                                                            command=self.display_speed)
        self.speed_button.grid(row=10, column=1, pady=(10, 0), padx=20, sticky="n")
        self.speed_button.set("1")
        self.speed_text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self,text='Video Speed:')
        self.speed_text.grid(row=10, column=1, pady=(10, 0), padx=0, sticky="w")
        self.speed_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self,text='1x')
        self.speed_value.grid(row=10, column=1, pady=(10, 0), padx=80, sticky="w")
        

        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.set("Dark")
        


    def open_input_dialog_event(self):
        dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Type in a number:", title="CTkInputDialog")
        print("CTkInputDialog:", dialog.get_input())

    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def change_scaling_event(self, new_scaling: str):
        new_scaling_float = int(new_scaling.replace("%", "")) / 100
        customtkinter.set_widget_scaling(new_scaling_float)

    def select_model(self):
        global cap, model
        model_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        if model_file:
            model = YOLO(model_file)
            #button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def select_video(self):
        global cap, filename
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        if filename:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

    def process_video(self):
        global cap, model, frame_dir
        frame_number = 0
        frame_count = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
        # Get the number of frames to skip from the Scale widget
        nfps = self.skipscale.get()
        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        n=int(fps/nfps)
        
        while frame_number < frame_count:
            for _ in range(n):
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    break
            if not ret:
                break
            x, clean_img=cap.read()
            results = model.predict(frame)
            confidence = self.confidence.get()/100
            image = plot_bboxes(frame, results[0].boxes.data, model.names, conf=confidence*100)
            frame_filename = os.path.join(frame_dir, f'frame_{frame_number:04d}.png')
            cv2.imwrite(frame_filename, image)
            # Calculate the time of the current frame
            frame_time = frame_number / fps
            
            # Format the frame time as a string in the minutes:seconds format
            minutes, seconds = divmod(int(frame_time), 60)
            frame_time_str = f'{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}'
            videoname = os.path.basename(filename)
            for box in results[0].boxes.data:
                class_name = model.names[int(box[-1])]
                im_confidence = box[-2]
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = box[:4]
                if class_name != 'No issues':
                    if im_confidence > confidence:
                        # Write the frame number, time, and object detection results to the CSV file
                        writer.writerow([videoname,frame_number, frame_time_str, class_name, im_confidence, x1, y1, x2, y2])
                        frame_filename = f'detection/{videoname}_frame_{int(frame_number):04d}.png'
                        cv2.imwrite(frame_filename, frame)
                        frame_filename = f'detection/{videoname}_frame_clean_{int(frame_number):04d}.png'
                        cv2.imwrite(frame_filename, clean_img)       
            progress_step=int(100 * frame_number / frame_count)/100    
            self.progressbar.set(progress_step)
            frame_number += n
        self.display_frames(frame_dir)
            
    def start_processing(self):
        global cap
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process_video)
        thread.start()

    def start_displaying(self):
        global cap, thread, video_state
        # Wait for the process_video thread to finish
        thread.join()
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
        self.display_frames()

    def toggle_pause(self):
        global is_paused
        is_paused = not is_paused
        if is_paused:
            self.play_pause_button.configure(text="Play")
        else:
            self.play_pause_button.configure(text="Pause")

    def update_frame(self, value):
        global current_frame
        current_frame = int(value)

    def next_frame(self):
        global current_frame
        current_frame += 1
        self.timeline.set(current_frame)

    def prev_frame(self):
        global current_frame
        current_frame -= 1
        self.timeline.set(current_frame)
    
    def display_speed(self,value):
        global xvel
        xvel=int(value[0])
        self.speed_value.configure(text=str(int(value[0])) + 'x')

    def display_frames(self,frame_dir):
        global is_paused, current_frame,xvel
        
        frame_label = self.video_label
        
        nfps=self.skipscale.get()
        #nfps = skip_scale.get()
        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print(fps)
        print(xvel)
        frame_delay = xvel*1/nfps
        print(frame_delay)
        frame_files = sorted(os.listdir(frame_dir))
        self.timeline.configure(from_=0, to=len(frame_files))
        while current_frame < len(frame_files):
            if current_frame<0 : break
        # rest of the code
            while is_paused:
                self.update()
                time.sleep(0.1)
            frame_file = frame_files[current_frame]
            self.timeline.set(current_frame)
            frame = Image.open(os.path.join(frame_dir, frame_file))
            photo = CTkImage(frame,size=(900,750))
            self.video_label.configure(image=photo)
            self.video_label.image = photo
            time.sleep(frame_delay)
            current_frame += 1    
            
    def update_confidence(self, value):
        self.confidence_value.configure(text=str(int(value)) + '%')
        
    def update_fps(self, value):
        self.skipscale_value.configure(text=int(value))
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
    if csvfile:
        csvfile.close()
    if cap:
        cap.release()
```

It shouldn't open a 2nd window but start the video processing and display the processed frames once it ended this. I've read that I should include the `__name__ == "__main__"` but I was already doing that so I don't know what's really going on.

Comment: Why are you a duplicated? `cap.read()`  Use this `clean_img` and pass to parameters instead of `frame`.  Comment out this for _ in range(n):
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    break
            if not ret:
                break

Comment: Comment out this too `#cv2.imwrite(frame_filename, frame)`

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following format for my tkinter Applications. Check out if that helps you. I am assuming by the second window you do not mean the command prompt window, right?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
app = MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OP's main app class is already inheriting from `customtkinter.CTk`. Instantiating `Tk` like this won't fix anything. This answer also won't work as-written (indentation errors notwithstanding) because there is no class called `MainApplication` defined anywhere in your code *or* OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue as a whole is a bit unclear. Can you upload a video or perhaps some screenshots of the issue so viewers can get a better picture of the issue?

Additionally, the way you've structured your code is also a bit iffy. You've put everything into the main `App` class, which is technically okay and compiles just fine but it does make your code almost entirely unreadable and makes it difficult to work on and follow. I personally tend to prefer separating everything up into classes (re: https://github.com/StarkOdinson612/QRAttendanceV2) because it helps debug things a lot easier.